# pandas summation per year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

python3, pandas version 0.23.4

Let's say we have a pandas DataFrame as follows

```
np.random.seed(45)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 20)}, index = pd.to_datetime(dd).sort_values(ascending=False))
```

Now, I would like to total the data in column A with respect to each year.  I could do:

```
gf_perYear = gf.groupby(by= gf.index.year)
gf_perYear.sum()

       A
2012  11
2013   8
2014  15
2015  44
2016  13
2017  11
```

However, I am wondering if there would be a way that would allow me to get the result posted in a new column right by the last day if each year, as shown below:

```
            A sum_per_year
2017-12-15  3           11
2017-11-27  0             
2017-07-24  5             
2017-06-28  3             
2016-11-07  4           13
2016-06-03  9             
2015-12-18  8           44
2015-10-16  1             
2015-09-18  5             
2015-07-15  9             
2015-04-09  6             
2015-03-18  8             
2015-02-18  7             
2014-10-21  8           15
2014-09-16  5             
2014-01-29  2             
2013-01-04  8            8
2012-12-28  1           11
2012-08-21  6             
2012-03-02  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `transform`

```
gf_perYear = gf.groupby(by= gf.index.year)
gf['new'] = gf_perYear.transform('sum')
```